# Teamcity Agent Setup: Incompatible runner: NAnt, Missing VCS plugins on agent: Subversion

Tags: svn, teamcity, nant

I seem to not have the right properties set on my agent.

What property value pairs do I have to specify in my buildagent.properties file in order to use NAnt and Subverison?

Currently my agent is listed as Incompatible with the following:

***Incompatible runner**: NAnt

**Missing VCS plugins on agent**: 
•Subversion*

I've the following curretntly set in my buildagent.properties file:

```
env.NAntHome=C\:\\Program Files\\nant-0.91\\bin
system.DotNetFramework2.0
```

Cheers.

Comment: I had the same issue. Restarting the build agent computer was enough to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TeamCity build agent comes bundled with Java implementation of SVN client (SVNKit), so you don't need to specify anything in buildagent.properties for subversion. If you get "Missing VCS plugins on agent: •Subversion", this might mean that agent update was interrupted at some point and SVN plugin is missing. 
To fix this you can stop the agent, delete {agent home}/plugins and start it again: it should download the plugins and update automatically.

Comment: On following you steps I kept ending up with an empty plugins directory. It took re-installing Teamcity altogether and setting the appropriate permissions -http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD65/Setting+up+and+Running+Additional+Build+Agents - on the plugins directory in order to meet the requirement I'd set. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the service account running the TeamCity Agent service has rights on the directory where it is installed.